# Why doesn't my arrow function return array but instead a function declaration

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I tried to write a arrow function to compute the square of only the positive integers ( not include the fractions).

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
const squareList = (arr) => {
    "use strict";

    const squaredIntegers = (arr) => {
        let arrayChoosen = arr.filter(ele => ele > 0 && Number.isInteger(ele));
        return arrayChoosen.map(x => x * x);
    }

    return squaredIntegers;
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

But the result is a function declaration, not a array as I expect. But when I try to modify the code in this way

```js
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
  let squaredIntegers = arr.filter(ele => ele > 0 && Number.isInteger(ele));
  squaredIntegers = squaredIntegers.map(val => val * val);
  return squaredIntegers;
};
```

Then it output the array I expect.
Why in the first case it doesn't work?

Comment: In the first example the function `squaredIntegers()` is never called, but only the function reference is returned. So why would you expect the result to be an array in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you return function name only - that is - reference to function.

Instead, you should call that function:

```
return squaredIntegers();
```

Your second example works fine because you are actually calling `arr.filter()` and assign it's value to `squaredIntegers`

Comment: Thank you. You help me clear the concept of arrow function

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the returned value of your `squaredIntegers` function, so try with this code:

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
const squareList = (arr) => {
    "use strict";

    const squaredIntegers = (a) => {
        let arrayChoosen = a.filter(ele => ele > 0 && Number.isInteger(ele));
        return arrayChoosen.map(x => x * x);
    }

    return squaredIntegers(arr);
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: Although you have fixed OPs code so that it works, your answer neglects to explain _why_ their code didn't work, which was actually the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `squaredIntegers` with `arr` for getting a new array.

```
return squaredIntegers(arr);
```

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
const squareList = (arr) => {
    "use strict";

    const squaredIntegers = (arr) => {
        let arrayChoosen = arr.filter(ele => ele > 0 && Number.isInteger(ele));
        return arrayChoosen.map(x => x * x);
    }

    return squaredIntegers(arr);
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the first `squareList` returns the function itself, rather than the function called on the input `arr`. You might `return` its invocation instead:

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
const squareList = (arr) => {
    "use strict";

    const squaredIntegers = (arr) => {
        let arrayChoosen = arr.filter(ele => ele > 0 && Number.isInteger(ele));
        return arrayChoosen.map(x => x * x);
    }

    return squaredIntegers(arr);
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you return a function when you need to return result of the function call. Check the corrected code.

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
const squareList = (arr) => {
    "use strict";

    const squaredIntegers = (arr) => {
        let arrayChoosen = arr.filter(ele => ele > 0 && Number.isInteger(ele));
        return arrayChoosen.map(x => x * x);
    }

    return squaredIntegers(arr);
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a function rather than a function call.

Change `return squaredIntegers;` to `return squaredIntegers(arr)`;

So it will become

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34];
const squareList = (arr) => {
    "use strict";

    const squaredIntegers = (arr) => {
        let arrayChoosen = arr.filter(ele => ele > 0 && Number.isInteger(ele));
        return arrayChoosen.map(x => x * x);
    }

    return squaredIntegers(arr);
};
// test your code
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```